# Integral equation to determine curve shapes

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, integral-equations

In the Cartesian plane, $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have a rectangular domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, with $x\in[0,a], y\in[0,b]$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Over a subinterval $x\in[x_{1},x_{2}]\subset [0,a]$, we have two arbitrary curves (or two families of curves) defined as $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$.

We need to find the family of curves $y_{1}(x)$ and $y_{2}(x)$ that satisfy the condition (if not exact zero, then approaching it):

$$ \int^{x_{2}}_{x_{1}} \left[y_{1}(x)-y_{2}(x)\right]\cos\frac{2\pi x}{a}dx \rightarrow0 $$

How can we proceed to find the form of such curves ($y_{1},y_{2}$)?  Even if we could assume the shape of one curve (e.g. say taking one of them as a specific known equation), how can we generally find the other curve?

Any insight/tips would be appreciated. Also, it would be useful to know the subbranches of applied math (or related books/literature) concerned with similar problems.

Comment: Try to write $y_1-y_2$ in [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series), as your condition is to have a Fourier coefficient near $0$.

Comment: The question is not clear. 1) Why do you need the value $b$? 2) What is wrong with just taking $y_1 \equiv y_2$?